# Python (Pandas) - Syntax Error - Invalid Syntax - writer.save()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I try to make this code work, but it have error:

```
for myname in mn:
    mydf = df.loc[df.Teacher_name == myname]
    mydf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = myname)
writer.save()

  File "<stdin>", line 4
    writer.save()
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

import=

```
import pandas as pd
```

writer =

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')
```

mn =

```
mn = df['name'].unique().tolist()

mn = ['Teacher A', 'Teacher B', 'Teacher C']
```

To make df was used this query:

```
df = pd.read_csv('XXX.csv', names=['Teacher_name', 'Studen_name','Extra'])
```

df otput:

```
        Teacher_name      Student_name    Extra                                                    
1       Teacher A         Student 1       xxxx
2       Teacher A         Student 2       xxxx
3       Teacher B         Student 3       xxxx
4       Teacher C         Student 4       xxxx
```

Comment: show how you initialize `writer` please.

Comment: Is your indentation correct? This *may* not be the issue, but it's good practice to use 4 spaces.

Comment: @WoodyPride writer = pd.ExcelWriter("MyData.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

Comment: @jpp 1 -4 spaces does not make any difference

Comment: OK, I suggest you include more of your code before these lines.

Comment: @jpp question updated, have a look please.

Comment: Trivial issues which you might want to check: change `df.Teacher_name` to `df['Teacher_name']`; change `sheet_name` to `sheetname`.

Comment: `import pandas pd` is missing `as`. I'm not sure that could be the cause but needs fixing.

Comment: @jpp TypeError: to_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sheetname', with second change, same issue.

Comment: @roganjosh Was typo, but thank you for this.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in REPL? I can't see what is causing these issues

Comment: @roganjosh to do this, I use python 3.6 (32-bit) (CMD style)

Comment: Really you should either be doing this with iPython (which at least allows you to define blocks with indentation already sorted) or running from a script. If indentation is changing the errors then it's probably coming from the fact you're using REPL.